# Store a users traversal path through a nested hierarchy

Tags: neo4j, cypher, hierarchical-data, nested-sets

I have a nested tree stored in Neo4j.  Where each node can have a `(n)-[:CHILD]->(c)` relationship with other nodes.  Allowing you to query the entire tree from a given node down with `MATCH (n)-[c:CHILD*]-(m)`.

What I am having trouble with, is figuring out how to store a path that a user takes as they walk through a tree.  For instance a query to return the path would be `(user)-[:USER_PATH*]->(node)`.

However the path has to remain along the lines of `:CHILD` relationships, it cannot jump outside of its branch.  A user path cannot jump from the leaf of one branch to a leaf of another branch, without first retracting its way back up the path it came from until it finds a fork that will walk down to it.

Also I do not think shortest path will work, because its not the shortest path I want, I want the users actual path. But it should disregard relationships that were abandoned as the user backed out of any branches.  It should not be leaving around dead paths.

How would I be able to update the graph after each node is walked to so these rules stay in tact??

It can be assumed that in drilling down into a new branch, it can only step through to one more set of siblings.  However all branches it came through are still open, so their siblings can be selected.

Best I can figure is that it needs to:

- "prefer" walking the `:USER_PATH` relationships as long as it can
- until it needs to break that path to get to the new node
- at which point it creates any new relationships
- then delete any old relationships that are no longer on that path

I have no idea how to accomplish that though.

I have spent a ton of time in trial and error and googling to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

---

Given the image below:

- red node = User
- green nodes = A valid node to be a new "target"
- blue nodes = invalid target node

So if you were to back out of the leaf node it is in currently, it would delete that final :RATIONAL_PATH relation in the chain.

Also the path should adjust to any of the green nodes that were selected, but keeping the existing :RATIONAL_PATH in tact for as far as possible.

[image]

Comment: I'm still rather fuzzy on what paths of :RATIONAL_PATH relationships are supposed to be paths to, or how they're supposed to be generated...are these individual relationships selected by some other sort of process? Or are you somehow trying to infer them from a `MATCH (n)-[c:CHILD*]-(m)` kind of query?

Comment: It sounds like the end result you want is a single path of :RATIONAL_PATH relationships to some end node, and you want a way to clean up paths the user explored but returned from. Is that what you're after? I'm assuming the backing out process will be creating :RATIONAL_PATH relationships in the direction back to previous nodes (opposite of the direction they came from). At what point do you want to attempt to clean up the extraneous paths?

Comment: Yes, a single :RATIONAL_PATH path from the root node down to some node in the tree.  But rather than go back in the opposite direction when they navigate I would want to just delete that relationship, so as to provide a one-way-path of nodes from root to target, I would prefer to delete the relationship that took it that far to begin with.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I updated the image to show nodes that should be allowed to be clicked on, and extended the :RATIONAL_PATH relation out to a leaf node.  I did them manually, but ideally there was  a pattern that would provide the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think removing the existing path and creating a new one with `shortestPath()` is probably the best way to go. The cost of reusing the existing path and performing cleanup is often going to be higher and more complex than simply starting over.

Otherwise, the approach to take would be to match down to the last node of your path, and then perform a shortestPath() to the new node, and create your path.

And then we'd have to perform cleanup. This would probably involve matching all paths along :RATIONAL_PATH relationships to the end node resulting in a group of paths. The one with the shortest distance is going to be the one we keep. We'd need to collect those relationships, collect the other relationships of other paths that are no longer valid, do some set subtraction to get the relationships not used in the shortest path, and deleting them.

That's quite a bit of work that should probably be avoided.

Comment: Right now I am basically just:   matching the root;  deleting all :RATIONAL_PATH completely for that node;   finding the shortest path, and create :RATIONAL_PATH between each;